# Nontrivial conjugacy class and simplicity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Prove that if $G$ has a nontrivial conjugacy class $K$ such that $|G|$ does not divide $|K|!$, then $G$ is not simple.

How can I prove this statement? I think that with the condition, I could find nontrivial normal subgroup. But I failed. Help me!

Comment: Hint: $G$ acts non-trivially on $K$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you. I solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the group $G$ act on $K$ via conjugation.

Then by such homomorphism $\phi$, with 1st isomorphism theorem, $|G/Ker\phi|||K|!$

If $Ker\phi={1}$, it contradicts the non-divisibility condition in problem.

If $Ker\phi=G$, it contradicts the nontriviality of conjugacy class $K$.

So we get nontrivial normal subgroup $Ker\phi$ which shows that G is not simple.